# arcpy; create points with XY and display them correctly

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a python script to add points to a feature class. The points have an XY value but they don't display where they should on the map. I've read [Adding new record with specific coordinates into shapefile using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115440/adding-new-record-with-specific-coordinates-into-shapefile-using-arcgis-for-desk) so I understand why it isn't working. And I know I can export the FC to a table, display XY data and save to a shapefile. My question is, can this all be automated in a python script and if so, what happens at the end when the I run the script to add another point?

Also I've tried using arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management and arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management but nothing seems to appear. I'd be grateful to anyone who gets back to me with some advise.
Thanks

Here is the code I'm trying;

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\MyWork\Assignment\folklore.gdb'

arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management('Folklore', 'x_coord', 'y_coord', 'folklore_Layer', "PROJCS['IRENET95_Irish_Transverse_Mercator',GEOGCS['GCS_IRENET95',DATUM['D_IRENET95',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',600000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',750000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-8.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.99982],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',53.5],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5022200 -15179500 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision", '#')
save_output = r'F:\MyWork\Assignment\studyquadsLyr.lyr'
save_output2 = r'F:\MyWork\Assignment\folklore.gdb/folklore'
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management('folklore_Layer', save_output)
arcpy.Delete_management(r'F:\MyWork\Assignment\folklore.gdb/folklore')
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('studyquadsLyr.lyr', save_output2)
```

Comment: Can you include the code you have so far?

Comment: Here is the code I'm using. It is creating the .lyr file. But nothing is display in ArcCatalog.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. Problem was I was trying to save the event layer. Seems you don't have to. Here is the code;

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\MyProject\Assignment\folklore.gdb'

arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management('Folklore', 'x_coord', 'y_coord', 'folklore_Layer', "PROJCS['IRENET95_Irish_Transverse_Mercator',GEOGCS['GCS_IRENET95',DATUM['D_IRENET95',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',600000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',750000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-8.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.99982],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',53.5],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-5022200 -15179500 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision", '#')

# run this once without the Delete line to create the shp file. From then on
# you delete the shp file in order to replace it with the new shp file plus the extra record.
arcpy.Delete_management(r'F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment\test_shp.shp')
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("folklore_Layer", "F:\EGM722 - Customising GIS apps\Assignment", "test_shp")
```